# Android transparent Fragment / GoogleMap

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps

I have a fragment holding a Google Map object that I'm overlaying on top of other UI elements. I would like to make this fragment / map be transparent. Here is the element:

```
// the fragment in xml:

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" >
</fragment>

// relevant Java code:

private GoogleMap map;

map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

How can I make this map be transparent?

Comment: What would you like to have transparent (or translucent)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code might work :

```
((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getView().setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent)
```

You can even create a subclass of `MapFragment` and override the `OnCreateView()` method to set the background to be transparent.